# Glide library | image not loading up

Tags: laravel, image, laravel-5, php-glide

I'm trying to enable this library for my localhost environment.

> http://glide.thephpleague.com/1.0/config/integrations/laravel/

Current Laravel version `5.5`

`gd2` is enabled in wamp extensions.

I can't seem to find where the problem is.

Path is OK, image exists on it.

See following code for server config.

```
$server = ServerFactory::create([
            'response' => new LaravelResponseFactory(app('request')),
            'source' => $source,
            //'cache' => new Filesystem(new Adapter('../storage/app/cache/')),
            'cache' => $cache,
            'cache_path_prefix' => '.cache',
            'base_url' => 'transform-img',
        ]);
```

Now I use this

```
return $server->getImageResponse($path, request()->all());
```

it does not give any error.

When I `dd()` this, I get this response.

```
StreamedResponse {#1151 ▼
  #callback: Closure {#1177 ▶}
  #streamed: false
  -headersSent: false
  +headers: ResponseHeaderBag {#1176 ▶}
  #content: null
  #version: "1.0"
  #statusCode: 200
  #statusText: "OK"
  #charset: null
}
```

Callback Closure:

```
#callback: Closure {#1252 ▼
    class: "League\Glide\Responses\SymfonyResponseFactory"
    this: LaravelResponseFactory {#1231 …}
    use: {▼
      $stream: stream resource @543 ▼
        timed_out: false
        blocked: true
        eof: false
        wrapper_type: "plainfile"
        stream_type: "STDIO"
        mode: "rb"
        unread_bytes: 0
        seekable: true
        uri: "D:\wamp\www\Bankrolla\storage\app/public\.cache/img/logo_no_text.png/32c8e67d979eab40a7ef6d1854f1f7cc"
        options: []
      }
    }
    file: "D:\wamp\www\Bankrolla\vendor\league\glide-symfony\src\Responses\SymfonyResponseFactory.php"
    line: "48 to 54"
  }
```

As statusCode shows `200` and there is no error for file not found, still it does not load any image but shows a placeholder on browser when I navigate.

What might be the issue? If I try to replace image name with any other random string I get error for image not found. so this means it does find the image. Though it fails to render the image.

I have googled, searched on their GitHub comments, could not find any problem similar as mine.

I only get a blank page/image if I load it directly.

[image]

Also I looked in to the cache directory, it includes the files and those files dimensions are resized. so I am not sure where it goes wrong even when it generates the cache files.

[image]

Maybe I am missing something here?

### Update

Value of `$source` variable:

```
Filesystem {#1225 ▼
  #adapter: Local {#1226 ▼
    #pathSeparator: "\"
    #permissionMap: array:2 [▼
      "file" => array:2 [▼
        "public" => 420
        "private" => 384
      ]
      "dir" => array:2 [▼
        "public" => 493
        "private" => 448
      ]
    ]
    #writeFlags: 2
    -linkHandling: 2
    #pathPrefix: "D:\wamp\www\Bankrolla\storage\app/public\"
  }
  #plugins: []
  #config: Config {#1229 ▼
    #settings: []
    #fallback: null
  }
}
```

Storage Directory in my public directory (it's a symbolic link of original storage)

[image]

Storage Directory of Laravel

[image]

The URL I am calling this from.

`{localhostDomainHere}/image/img/logo_no_text.png?w=100&h=100&fit=crop-center`

Comment: Do you have your images in the location you've set as `'source' => $source,`?

Comment: Yes. location is OK.

Comment: @thefallen
Yes. location is OK.
This is why cache is generated fine. and when i open cache file its a resized image.
Thou in return it sends out a broken image.?

Comment: @SizzlingCode could the problem be with your PHP memory limit? If not could you try with `ImageMagick` php extension also,  since glide supports it... And please check the logs, as the answer is probably there...

Comment: @SizzlingCode and BTW are you sure you sure you don't have any special web server cache entries which may cause this misbehavior?

Comment: @Bart
Tried both libraries.
And not sure what you mean by web server cache entries, As i have no Cache enabled in my localhost.
I am working on localhost.

Comment: @SizzlingCode so what do you have in logs (webserver, php, laravel) when you make this request?

Comment: $source => what is its value ? does it have proper file access permissions ?

Comment: @samo
it can read file, it can resize image and save a cache file. shared the image at the end for cached images list.
But when returning the cache file for viewing/display it does not work and gives black screen.

Comment: check this https://github.com/thephpleague/glide/issues/35#issuecomment-270723994 and this https://github.com/thephpleague/glide/issues/35#issuecomment-319195817  . hope this helps.

Comment: @samo
Thankyou, 
i tried setting headers as explained in that github, but still no solution. same old, same old.

Comment: can you post details of  #callback: Closure {#1177 ▶}

Comment: @samo
added the closure

Comment: if i want to replicate your problem, i need to install the package and and upload an image, right ? anything else

Comment: @samo
No, nothing else. i followed the the package documentation.

Comment: it is running great on my system, can you post the value of $source here ?

Comment: @samo
Added the value of source variable.

Comment: @samo
its working on the live server, using s3 storage of aws.
`https://billfolda.com/transform-img/offer/cover/119_h-1x.jpg?w=370&amp;h=240&amp;fit=crop-center`

Comment: put image in storage/app/public

Comment: post image of your content in storage/app/public in local and post your route code as well as route url you are calling

Comment: @samo
updated the content.

Comment: any idea of this ? i got this problem too but dont know how to fix up. and so sad some image showed and some image didnt show (blank page)

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if you already fixed it. But we encountered the same problem a few days ago. After a long search, we found out that the error is caught by a new line in a config:

[image: config file]

So check all your config files for space or newline before openings tag. Otherwise, your response is not a valid response anymore and you will get the empty box.

If it is not a config file you need to check all the files that are loaded on the request.

Answer (score 0):

the path mentioned by $source => put images there. if it is 1.jpg, then call the url server_url/img/1.jpg . img is from your route for the function you posted in question. In my case $source as well as $cache was /storage/app and i put image in it and called the route on that image. Hope this helps you.

Check this

[image]
This is my code :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Filesystem\Filesystem;
use League\Glide\Responses\LaravelResponseFactory;
use League\Glide\ServerFactory;

class GlideController extends Controller
{
    public function show(Filesystem $filesystem, $path)
    {
        $server = ServerFactory::create([
            'response' => new LaravelResponseFactory(app('request')),
            'source' => $filesystem->getDriver(),
            'cache' => $filesystem->getDriver(),
            'cache_path_prefix' => '.cache',
            'base_url' => 'img',
        ]);

        return $server->getImageResponse($path, request()->all());
    }
}
```

route :

```
Route::get('/img/{path}', 'GlideController@show')->where('path', '.*');
```

this is the content of my storage/app

[image]

Comment: already have the route defined liked this.
`Route::get('/transform-img/{path}', 'ImageController@show')->where('path', '.*');`

Comment: but you are calling this "{localhostDomainHere}/image/img/logo_no_text.png?w=100&h=100&fit=crop-center" . you should call "{localhostDomainHere}/transform-img/img/logo_no_text.png?w=100&h=100&fit=crop-center"